# I can't change my vote to close, bug?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

I voted to close a question, then realized it was not the best fit. So I went to change my vote, and saw there was no option to do this:

[image]

Not a big deal, I thought. I can retract (seeing as that's my only option really) and then re-vote to close.

But! It apparently is not meant to work that way, as I am met with this when I try to recast a new vote for the reason I wanted:

[image]

My initial thought was wait a minute, but that did not help.

Looking through Meta, it appears this [has come up before:](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5481/change-accidental-vote) although the answer is not very definitive on why this occurs.

> Votes can only be undone when the post is edited. If your vote really
>   was accidental, you can resort to editing the post and then changing
>   the vote.

And this has been the tone of a few similar question, be careful next time or edit the question.

Is this a bug, and oversight, or is there something I am not getting here?

As an update, editing the question did not allow me to recast a vote!

And, after @NHinkle answered below, why is this not possible and can it be added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you're quoting is about regular up/down votes on a question.

You can only vote to close once, and you can only retract the vote once. After that, you cannot vote to close again unless the question is re-opened.

For more details, see the relevant feature request on MSO: [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

When you retract your vote, the confirmation dialog informs you that you cannot vote again after retracting your initial vote:

[image: no revote screenshot]

Comment: Hmm, so intentional it cannot be recast? Is there a way to at least warn the user that un-doing one mistake might cause another mistake that can not be undone?

Comment: @AthomSfere it already does this. See my edits above.

Comment: OK, dang... I apparently glossed over that.